# ошибка "Thread1: signal SIGABRT" (Swift 3, xcode 8)

Tags: swift3, firebase

Пишу код на Swift 3 в Xcode 8. Все делаю точно, как в видеоуроке, но при запуске программы появляется ошибка: **"Thread1: signal SIGABRT"**, указывающая на строку `class AppDelegate`.

Описание ошибки:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'No default Storage bucket
>   found. Did you configure Firebase Storage properly?'

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Напишите что делаете, какой пример.

Comment: @VAndrJ могу скинуть сам проект. Работаю с Firebase - создаю аккаунт пользователя

Comment: Можете добавить пример где это воспроизводится? Ну и какой урок.

Comment: Все очень просто проверь все в mainsotryboard у тебя скорее всего какой то левый outlet либо он просто отвалился, смотри в сторону аутлетов